# Change value of variable in outer-function

Tags: python

how can I change the value of a variable in an outer function? 
Actually, I have the following:

```
def outer():
    variab = ""
    #some code

    def inner():
        # some code
        variab = "new_value"

    print variab
```

After execution, the print-statement should be equal to "new_value". How can this be done?
Thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: You never call `inner()` so why should that line have executed?

Comment: @Cyber `#some code` would presumably include a call to `inner()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, in this simple case you could return the desired value from `inner()` and assign it when calling `inner()`. But let's assume that this is a simplified example, and that you are in fact changing multiple variables, or returning `inner` somewhere else where it will be called multiple times and need to reexamine its variable.

In Python 3 you can declare `variab` as `nonlocal`, which would allow you to change it. In Python 2, the only way is to switch to mutating an object with state freshly created on each call to `outer`. For example, using a list:

```
def outer():
    variab = [""]
    #some code including, presumably, a call to inner()

    def inner():
        # some code
        variab[0] = "new_value"

    print variab[0]
```

Nicer variants of this can be achieved, e.g. by making `variab` contain a dict or a Python instance with mutable `__dict__`. An elegant idiom is to use the `__dict__` of the `inner` function itself as the container:

```
def outer():
    def inner():
        # some code
        inner.variab = "new_value"

    inner.variab = ""
    #some code including, presumably, a call to inner()    
    print inner.variab
```

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to do this is **explicitly**:

```
def outer():
    variab = ""
    #some code

    def inner(variab):
        # some code
        variab = "new_value"
        return variab

    variab = inner(variab)

    print variab
```

Now you don't have to worry about scoping, can test `inner` in isolation, etc. It is clear to the reader that `inner` requires access to `variab` to do its thing, and that `variab` may be different after the call.

See [PEP-0020](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): *"Explicit is better than implicit"*; and *"Readability counts"*.

Answer (score 0):

```
def outer():
    variab = { 'value': "" }
    def inner():
        variab['value'] = "new_value"
```

Hope this helps.